# Laravel simplify nested relation output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I get all items owned by authenticated user.

$items=Auth::user()->with('items')->get();

In my view i can access items collection, but instead of title_id want to retrieve item_title value.
Currently i'm able to get item_title value using code below:

$item->title->title

Is it possible to simplify it to retrieve title like this:
$item->title
?

Here is my models and relations:

```
Users
    id
    username
Item
    id
    user_id
    title_id
Item_Titles
    id
    title
```

**User model:**

```
  public function items()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('Item', 'user_id', 'id');
  }
```

**Item model:**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
} 

public function title()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('ItemTitle','title_id','id');
}
```

**ItemTitle model:**

```
public function item()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Item', 'title_id', 'id');
}
```

**UPDATE**

Excuse me probably I wasn't clear. To be precise - I just want to find Eloquent alternative to:

```
$items=Item::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->leftJoin('item_titles', 'item.title_id', '=', 'item_titles.id')->get();

@foreach ($items as $item)
    {{ $item->title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your relationship function to

Item model:

```
public function title()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('ItemTitle','title_id','id')->first()->title;
}
```

You will need to call it as `$item->title()` unless you also do

```
public function getTitleAttribute(){
   return $this->title();
}
```

You might get some funny stuff with everything being called 'title' but with this `$item->title` should also work I think

Comment: a bit tricky, maybe better to use join instead of eloquent relations?

Comment: Its not tricky it's how to use the framework. You requirement is a bit needless to be honest just reference the nested relationship it better reflects the logical structure of your code and makes it more readable

Comment: This wouldn't work. `get` returns a collection. A collection doesn't have the title property.

Comment: @ThomasKim Then use `first` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. It looks like you setup a many-to-many relationship with the `Item` model being the pivot table.

**User Model**

```
public function titles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ItemTitle', 'items');
}
```

Note: Change `ItemTitle` to the correct namespace. Also, change `items` to the `Item` model's table name.

You can also define the inverse relationship like this:

**ItemTitle Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'items');
}
```

From there, you can get all the authenticated user's `ItemTitles` like this:

```
$titles = Auth::user()->titles;
```

Link to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**Editing based on the comments below (thanks to @ash for helping clarify and for his suggestion):**

The other answer is more along the lines of what you are trying to achieve so I would recommend taking a look at that. However, there is an error in your question. This does not return items:

```
$items=Auth::user()->with('items')->get();
```

That returns all users with their items eager loaded. To see proof of this, if you `dd($items)`, you will most likely see every single user in the database.

That is most likely not what you want to do. To get all items for the authenticated users, you should do this:

```
$items = Auth::user()->items;
```

It's that simple to get a collection of items. This will run 2 queries - 1 to get the user and another to get all of his items.

Comment: Auth::user()->titles isn't obvious. titles related to Item, not to User. I assume titles collection should be somehow merged with Item collection. Or join should be used instead of eloquent relations.

Comment: I assumed you wanted it to be 1 level because that's sounded like what you wanted in your question. I'll edit my answer though.

Comment: This is terrible, ideally you would use `first` and `pluck` accordingly.

Comment: @ash Except that changes the question. If someone asks how to get the children of the parent, you don't answer the question with a way to get one child.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  It's either a m:m and the OP wants to do the impossible or its a 1:1. I would simply run `lists` into `implode` from the `title` relationship.

Comment: I deleted my comments that might have confused the OP (since I was mistaken / confused actually). The other answer is more correct if you do not want to create a many-to-many relationship, which is what I thought you wanted based on the "simplify nested relation" in the title.

Comment: @ash yes it is 1:1 (item and item_title)

Comment: @ThomasKim thank you for involvement. I've updated question with some details.